# (Angular 5/6) unit test for a patch request with httpClient

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular6

I am trying to write a test case for a patch HTTP request,
Not having any idea how to pass body for the request so getting an error in service file while body formation.

Here is what I have tried.

```
   service.patchCustomer(location : Location,null).subscribe(data=>{
    expect(data).toEqual('false');
  });
  const request = httpMock.expectOne(`/api/myapp/patchMe?token=null`);
  expect(request.request.method).toBe('PATCH');
  request.flush( 'false' , { status: 200, statusText: 'No Data' });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.